# При загрузке Windows вылезает ESET Online Scanner. Помогите удалить

Tags: windows, вирусы, автозагрузка

Не могу с компьютера зайти на свою страницу. Появляется вот это сообщение: "Для очистки компьютера вам нужно будет загрузить и запустить это бесплатное средство проверки `ESET Online Scanner`. Оно проверит ваш компьютер на наличие вредоносного ПО и попытается его удалить.
Нажимая "Загрузить", вы соглашаетесь с Условиями ESET Online Scanner.". Но у меня есть антивирусная программа и ничего более я загружать не хочу. Помогите решить проблему. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

1. Предлагаю провериться антивирусом касперского / доктором вебом.
2. Возможно хостинг взломан и впаривает вирусную утилиту. Без адреса гадать бессмысленно.

Comment: При чём тут хостинг? У человека явно проблемы с десктопом.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно загрузить компьютер в `безопасном режиме`. При загрузке windows быстро нажимать клавишу `F8`.
2. После того как появится рабочий стол - нажать сочетание клавиш `Win+R`. Клавиша `Win` находится слева снизу между `Ctrl` и `Alt`.
3. В появившемся окне набрать `msconfig` и нажать `Enter`.
4. Перейти на вкладку `Автозагрузка` и выкинуть оттуда всё, кроме `ctfmon`.
5. Перезагрузиться в нормальный режим.